# Type error on a length function

Tags: ocaml

I have a very interesting first project to learn OCaml, after creating a personnal `list` type like such:

```
type 'a my_list = Item of ('a * 'a my_list) | Empty;;
```

And filling it up like such:

```
let num_list = Item (1, Item (2, Item(3, Empty)));;
```

I have to recode many functions of the list module which will be adapted to my new list type as showed above.

I'm starting off with `Length` which sounds the easiest and a good one to start with.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let rec length my_list =
match my_list with
| [] -> 0
| head::rest -> 1 + (length rest);;
```

Which has the right definition:

```
val length : 'a list -> int = <fun>
```

But when I pass my newly created list I get the following error:

> Error: This expression has type int my_list
>          but an expression was expected of type 'a list

What am I missing out?

I'm enjoying OCaml so far, and would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually using your own `'a my_list` type but the original `'a list`.

Your function has to do a pattern matching, not on a `'a list` but on a `'a my_list`:

```
let rec my_length my_list = 
  match my_list with
  | Empty -> 0
  | Item (_, rest) -> 1 + (my_length rest);;
```

The type that you get now is :

```
val my_length : 'a my_list -> int = <fun>
```

Now you are using your own `'a my_list` type.

Comment: Oh, I see ! Thank you very much for your help, that'll help me for the other functions for sure.